# How can i use the return result from function?

Tags: python

I'm learing python and I'm not sure how to solve my problem. I created a class and definition that generates an array with numbers, then i want to create another def that will multiply each number array. I tried something like this, but i got the error.

```
class Hydrology():

    def wieloktornosc_tm():
        tab = list(i for i in range(600, 43800, 600))
        return tab

    def wielokrotnosc_nat_deszczu():
        wielokrotnosc_q = []
        for i in self.wieloktornosc_tm():
            q = (15.347 * (1013 / i ** 0.667))
        return wielokrotnosc_q.append(q)



print(Hydrologia.wielokrotnosc_tm())
print(Hydrologia.wieloktornosc_nat_deszczu())
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Why do you want to use class or rather static method? Why not simple standalone function? What do you think `append` would return ?

Comment: Unlike in Java in Python you don't need like classes to have functions/methods.

Comment: You probably meant to append in the loop, and to simply `return wielokrotnosc_q` at the end

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you meant to do this?

```
def wielokrotnosc_nat_deszczu():
        wielokrotnosc_q = []
        for i in self.wieloktornosc_tm():
            q = (15.347 * (1013 / i ** 0.667))
            wielokrotnosc_q.append(q)
        return wielokrotnosc_q
```

With your code it will always return `None`

As suggested in the comments you can achieve the same effect using a standalone function like so:

```
def wielokrotnosc_nat_deszczu():
    wielokrotnosc_q = []
    for i in range(600, 43800, 600):
        q = (15.347 * (1013 / i ** 0.667))
        wielokrotnosc_q.append(q)
    return wielokrotnosc_q
```

Using another function to create the `tab` would make sense if you are passing parameters to the function that will produce different results as a consequence of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of errors (wrong names, missing `self` in method names, not appending in a loop) in your snippet, this code is working:

```
class Hydrology():

    @staticmethod
    def wielokrotnosc_tm():
        tab = list(i for i in range(600, 43800, 600))
        return tab

    @classmethod
    def wielokrotnosc_nat_deszczu(cls):
        wielokrotnosc_q = []
        for i in cls.wielokrotnosc_tm():
            q = (15.347 * (1013 / i ** 0.667))
            wielokrotnosc_q.append(q)
        return wielokrotnosc_q


print(Hydrology.wielokrotnosc_tm())
print(Hydrology.wielokrotnosc_nat_deszczu())
```

If you want to discuss changes wirte me a pm

Comment: Thank, you it works perfectly, how can i pm you ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this variation instead:

```
class Hydrology():

    # You need to have the self keyword in every
    # method definition and in case you need
    # to add arguments then (self, arg1, arg2, ...etc)
    def wieloktornosc_tm(self):
        tab = [i for i in range(600, 43800, 600)]
        return tab

    def wielokrotnosc_nat_deszczu(self):
        wielokrotnosc_q = []
        for i in self.wieloktornosc_tm():
            q = (15.347 * (1013 / i ** 0.667))
        return wielokrotnosc_q.append(q)

# You need to create the class object first.
Hydrologia = Hydrology()

# And then access its methods
print Hydrologia.wieloktornosc_tm()
print Hydrologia.wielokrotnosc_nat_deszczu()
```